# Promise not completing on rejection

Tags: javascript, http, promise, axios, interceptor

So I have a form that submits with the following function:

```
const formSubmit = async (formData) => {
  const response = await SubmissionsResource.create(formData)
  const { data, status } = response
  console.log('Request completed.')
  if (status === 201) {
    toast.success('Submission created.')
  } else {
    toast.error('Something went wrong.')
    console.error(data)
  }
}
```

Which uses the following:

```
const SubmissionsResource = {
  create: ({ formData }) => (
    Request.privatePost(apiUrl('submissions'), formData)
  ),
}
```

Which uses the following:

```
export const Request = {
  privateRequest: ({ data, method, params, url }) => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
      request.headers.authorization = getBearerToken()
      return request
    }, (error) => Promise.reject(error))

    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config

        // If request is coming from a sign in attempt
        if (error.response.status === 401 && originalRequest.url.includes('auth/token')) {
          return Promise.reject(error)
        }

        // If request is coming from elsewhere, assume token might be expired
        if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
          originalRequest._retry = true
          const refresh_token = LocalStorageService.getRefreshToken()
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${API_BASE}/oauth/token`,
            { client_id, client_secret, grant_type: 'refresh_token', refresh_token }
          )
          if (response.status === 200) {
            LocalStorageService.setUser(response.data)
            axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = getBearerToken()
            return axios(originalRequest)
          }
          return Promise.reject(error)
        }
        return Promise.reject(error)
      }
    )
    return axios({ method, url, data, params })
  },
  privatePost: (url, data) => (
    Request.privateRequest({ method: 'post', data, url })
  )
}
```

When the response is successful, I always see the "Request completed" log, and I see the `toast.success` message. However, when the request fails, I never see the "Request completed" log, nor the `toast.error` message.

The axios interceptor should retry once if the response comes back unauthorized (401 status code), which it successfully does, and in all other cases, reject the promise and return the error.

`Request.privateRequest` should reject the promise and return the error to `Request.privatePost`, which should return back to `SubmissionsResource.create`, and then finally to `formSubmit`. However, instead of completing the promise and returning an error, it just halts the entire function and doesn't ever get to the "Request completed" log.

I'm assuming this is due to an incorrect understanding with promises on my end, but I can't figure out what that is. Why isn't the promise being completed and continuing on to the next line within `formSubmit`?

Comment: I don't know any of these APIs, but generally, you can `throw new Error(x)` instead of `return Promise.reject(x)` to force promise chains to "unravel". Try that and see if it fixes it.... Another thing you can try: Use the default debugger, try setting breakpoints and see where the control flow goes and what the library does with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By returning Promise.reject(), you're telling axios to reject the promise returned by the network request, but the calling code doesn't catch any rejection.

Try try-ing:

```
const formSubmit = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const response = await SubmissionsResource.create(formData)
    const { data, status } = response
    console.log('Request completed.');
    toast.success('Submission created.')
  } catch(error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401)
      toast.error('Bad news: 401.');
    else 
      toast.error('Some other kind of bad news.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thanks!